# weak convergence of probability measures and unbounded functions with bounded expectation

Tags: probability, functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, weak-convergence

Assume that $\mu^n$ are probability measures on $R$ that convergence weakly(-*) to $\mu$, i.e for all $f \in C_b (R)$ (bounded and continuous), we have that $\int f(x) \mu^n(dx) \rightarrow \int f(x) \mu(dx)$.

Assume that $g \in C(R)$ is an unbounded function (for example $g(x)=x$) but assume that the integral of $\mu^n$ wrt to $|g|$ is uniformly bounded, i.e. $\sup_n  \int |g(x)| \mu^n(dx) \leq C$

Let us call $g_k(x)$ the function such that $g_k(x)=g(x)$ for $x \in [-k,k]$ and $g_k(x) = g(k)$ for $x>k$ and similar for $x<-k$.

Hence $g_k$ is bounded and continuous, hence $\int g_k(x) \mu^n(dx) \rightarrow \int g_k(x) \mu(dx)$ for each $k$.

Further we have by dominant converging theorem that for each $n$ we have $\int g_k(x) \mu^n(dx) \rightarrow \int g(x) \mu^n(dx)$

**Question**

Does this also imply that $\int g(x) \mu^n(dx) \rightarrow \int g(x) \mu(dx)$ ?

**Alternative question**

If thats wrong for general $g$ is it true for the example $g(x)=x$?

Answer (score 3):

take $g(x)=x, \  \mu_n=(1-\frac{1+(-1)^n}{n})\delta_0+\frac{1+(-1)^n}{n}\delta_n$.

Comment: Why are the $(-1)^n$ parts are necessary? To me it seems also be a counter example without these terms, right?

Comment: @mimi You are right, but with the $(-1)^n$ part we obtain that the sequence $(\int gd\mu_n)_n$ is not necessarily convergent.