# Convergence of unbounded functionals

Tags: probability-theory

Let $\mu_n$ be a sequence of random measures on the metric space $(\mathbb{R},d)$ that converges in some mode to a measure $\mu$. The definition of weak convergence is:
\begin{equation} \int_\mathbb{R} f(x) d\mu_n(x) \to \int_\mathbb{R} f(x) d\mu(x),
\end{equation}
for all bounded continuous functions $f$. The portmanteau lemma gives other characterizations, but they always deal with bounded functions. Now the question is: when the above convergence holds for unbounded continuous functions $f$? Are there hypotheses on $f$ and/or $\mu_n$ and $\mu$ that guarantee the above convergence?

Comment: "in the same sense" is impossible since the first convergence is a convergence of measures while the second is a convergence of numbers. Please rephrase.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, Did. Ok, now I have rephrased having in mind that the LHS and the RHS are RVs. Can I see the problem in this way? That is, the integral on the right is a RV, say $X_n$, and the integral on the right is another RV, say $X$, and I am asking when $X_n\to X$ according to some mode of convergence (of course, since both $X_n$ and $X$ are actually integrals, we have to set some conditions on the support, the measure, and the function $f$).

Comment: Now the question makes sense--unfortunately it is so soft that it verges on the shapeless, I am afraid... :-)

Comment: Is this immediate? If $f\in C_b(\mathbb{R})$, then the result would follow from the [portemanteau theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_measures#Weak_convergence_of_measures), but the case of this post is different. [Here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/867977/weak-convergence-of-probability-measures-and-unbounded-functions-with-bounded-ex) there is a similar question where it was shown a counterexample (there, the moments of the measure are not bounded). So maybe by requiring finite moments, the result would follow, otherwise I don't think it is true.

Comment: Shapeless $\ne$ immediate.

Comment: What do you mean with "shapeless"? Is is not well-posed? May you give me some hint? Thanks :)

Comment: I note that the question is difficult to answer because it is too imprecise and you ask me to answer it? Funny.

Comment: Ok, just rephrased the whole question. Is the question still too vague?